# How can make TypeScript in WebStorm to parse alias of webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack, webstorm

I using TypeScript (2.6.2) in WebStorm (2017.3) with webpack (2.6.1).

I create some alias of webpack:

```
//webpack.config.js
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
  },
},
```

WebStorm told me some error messages when I use alias in TypeScript:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module '@/src/short-night/Axis'.
```

But the project can run with no error by webpack

I had selected `webpack.config.js` and `tsconfig.json` in WebStorm setting.

The full project see [github: pea3nut/timeline](https://github.com/pea3nut/timeline/tree/stackoverflow)

What can I do to make WebStorm understand such alias?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) in `tsconfig.json` is the right way to go. And you have it set up already. But the issue is that you have your TypeScript files located in the parent folder of the directory where `tsconfig.json` resides. So the only `.ts` file included in your `tsconfig.json` is `develop/main.ts`.
From https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html:

```
The presence of a tsconfig.json file in a directory indicates that the directory is the root of a TypeScript project. If the "files" and "include" are both left unspecified, the compiler defaults to including all TypeScript (.ts, .d.ts and .tsx) files in the containing directory and subdirectories except those excluded using the "exclude" property.
```

So, you have to move `tsconfig.json` to the project root and change the paths there accordingly:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./develop/dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2017", "dom"],
    "baseUrl":".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*" :["./*"]
    },
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you! I Changing `"@" :["."]` to `"@/*" :["./*"]`, it works! And I have set `-p path/to/tsconfig-dir` in Typescript's options in Webstorm settings before asking a question.